# Pass subroutine name as string to use subs as general purpose input validation

Tags: excel, vba

I read through several posts about similar problems and tried many solutions offered by this and other communities. I cannot tailor any of these to my specific needs.

I have an Excel workbook that generates a timesheet and a detailed job report based on the information provided in a userform.

The job report and the timesheet are exported to an Access table (or imported from said table to be edited or deleted).

I have a working version with repetitive code for validating the userform inputs.

There are eight inputs that must meet criteria.
i) must be a number
ii) must not be less than a minimum value
iii) must not be greater than a maximum value

I have a subroutine for each of these inputs that checks these criteria using `BeforeUpdate`, and calls another subroutine to make visible changes to the userform to alert the user of an invalid entry (alter the label color and caption, textbox or dropbox color, etc.).

Using `AfterUpdate`, I have a subroutine for each of the eight inputs that reverts these changes once a valid entry has been made.

This means I have 24 subroutines with basically the same code, where I feel there should only be three subroutines that can be used more generally.

Here is the code I have for these subroutines, as it is being used for one specific input:

Sub #1

```
Private Sub NumberOfTechs_BeforeUpdate(ByVal CAncel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Not IsNumeric(numberOfTechs) Then
       Call NumberOfTechsInvalid("Must be a number!", numberOfTechsLabel, numberOfTechs)
       CAncel = True
    Else
        If numberOfTechs < 1 Then
            Call NumberOfTechsInvalid("Cannot be less than 1!", numberOfTechsLabel, numberOfTechs)
            CAncel = True
        ElseIf numberOfTechs > 6 Then
            Call NumberOfTechsInvalid("Cannot exceed 6!", numberOfTechsLabel, numberOfTechs)
            CAncel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Sub #2

```
Private Sub NumberOfTechsInvalid(errorCaption As String, targetLabel As Object, targetControl As Object)
    targetLabel.caption = errorCaption
    targetLabel.ForeColor = rgbRed
    targetControl.BackColor = rgbPink
    targetControl.SelStart = 0
    targetControl.SelLength = Len(targetControl)
End Sub
```

Sub # 3

```
Private Sub NumberOfTechs_AfterUpdate()
    numberOfTechsLabel.ForeColor = Me.ForeColor
    numberOfTechsLabel = "Number Of Techs"
    numberOfTechs.BackColor = rgbWhite

    ' Call next subroutine
End Sub
```

I have a comment at the bottom of sub#3 that says "call next subroutine". This is where I am having difficulty.

I can pass the minimum and maximum values as variables, as well as specify the target control and label based on which user input triggers the call to sub#1.

The issue is passing the next subroutine as a string.

I tried placing these subroutines in their own module and using `Application.Run`. I tried using `CallByName` with these subs within the userform code.

Comment: I may not have understood, but I think you might need a class module. Google and see if that looks like it might fit the bill.

Comment: So you've got 8 textBoxes and 8 Labels with the name of the Label as follows: 'nameoftextbox'label? The minimum and maximum values you know beforehand per Textbox? You could use a Class to catch the events and use only 3 subs

Comment: Thanks a million guys! I haven't come up with a solution as of yet, but it seems that class modules is the best way to go about this. There's  still lots for me to learn about how to create and use classes but I appreciate the helpful advice!